# Using logical operators to shorten a variable code

Tags: r, logical-operators, operator-precedence

I'm trying to code a variable for metabolic syndrome with 5 criteria Obesity(3 possible binary outcomes) Insulin resistance (3 possible binary outcomes) Dyslipidemia TGC (3 possible binary outcomes) Dyslipidemia HDL (2 possible binary outcomes) and Hipertension (4 possible binary outcomes). If a subject is positive for any 3 of these 5 criteria he would be considered positive for metabolic syndrome.

I have tryed to combine these in C5,3 considering that any subjects positive for 4 or 5 criteria would be covered by proxy. But my code got too big as I tried to cover any possible combination. Is it possible to make my code smaller using operator precedence to make it more compact?

```
METSYN <- array (NA,dim = dim(BancoTOTAL)[1] )
for (i in 1:791){  
  METSYN[i] <- ifelse ( #OID1 OID2
    BancoTOTAL$sexo.x[i] == 0 && BancoTOTAL$cintura.x[i] > 90 
                       && BancoTOTAL$Glic[i] >= 100 
                       && BancoTOTAL$TRIG[i] > 150 
                       |BancoTOTAL$sexo.x[i] == 1 && BancoTOTAL$cintura.x[i] > 80 
                       && BancoTOTAL$Glic[i] >= 100 
                       && BancoTOTAL$TRIG[i] > 150 
                       |BancoTOTAL$IMC[i] > 30
                       && BancoTOTAL$Glic[i] >= 100 
                       && BancoTOTAL$TRIG[i] > 150

and soon
, 1, 0)
}
```

Here is my reworked code using intermediate categorical variables

```
METSYN <- array(NA, dim = dim(BancoTOTAL)[1])
    for (i in 1:(dim(BancoTOTAL)[1])){
      METSYN[i] <- ifelse(
        #OID1
        BancoTOTAL$obesity[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$insulinR[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$dyslipidemiaTGC[i] == 1
        #OID2
        |BancoTOTAL$obesity[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$insulinR[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$dyslipidemiaHDL[i] == 1
        #OIH
        |BancoTOTAL$obesity[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$insulinR[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$HBP[i] == 1
        #OD1D2
        |BancoTOTAL$obesity[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$dyslipidemiaTGC[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$dyslipidemiaHDL[i] == 1
        #OD1H
        |BancoTOTAL$obesity[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$dyslipidemiaTGC[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$HBP[i] == 1
        #OD2H
        |BancoTOTAL$obesity[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$dyslipidemiaHDL[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$HBP[i] == 1
        #ID1D2
        |BancoTOTAL$obesity[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$dyslipidemiaTGC[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$dyslipidemiaHDL[i] == 1
        #ID1H
        |BancoTOTAL$insulinR[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$dyslipidemiaTGC[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$HBP[i] == 1
        #ID2H
        |BancoTOTAL$insulinR[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$dyslipidemiaHDL[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$HBP[i] == 1
        #D1D2H
        |BancoTOTAL$dyslipidemiaTGC[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$dyslipidemiaHDL[i] == 1
        && BancoTOTAL$HBP[i] == 1
        , 1, 0 )
    }
```

Comment: I would just check for all the criteria once, and then check if the length of this vector is greater than 3.

Comment: Using a intermediate vector? How can I code that (I'm a total noob in R)?

Comment: I tried to work around it using intermediate variables, it made the code a lot more compact, but it is still not very elegant.

Comment: Can you please provide me a sample dataset with `dput`. I'll look into it and try to help you.

Comment: This is my reworked code

Comment: Please provide a sample with `dput(BancoTOTAL)`that makes working with your code much easier

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? (using your intermediate categorial variables)

```
METSYN <- unlist(lapply(1:dim(BancoTOTAL)[1], function (x){
  (BancoTOTAL$obesity[x]+BancoTOTAL$insulinR[x]+BancoTOTAL$dyslipidemiaTGC[x]+BancoTOTAL$dyslipidemiaHDL[x]+BancoTOTAL$HBP[x])>=3
}))
```